What happens if you factor in the energy required to switch between the reservoirs and insulating stand of the Carnot engine?
I'm reading about the Carnot cycle (as a non-physicist!) and much of the focus is on the idealisation around the infinite time needed due to the requirement of only infinitesimal differences in temperature between the gas and the reservoirs.
However I'm more confused by the fact that, at various points in the cycle the gas in the piston is switched from being in contact with the hot reservoir, to being insulated, to being in contact with the cold reservoir. The work of this switching process surely consumes free energy and, given that its necessary for the cycle to occur, I'm struggling to understand why this isn't included in the calculations for energy & entropy changes throughout the cycle?
Unless it is somehow included in a manner that I'm missing?
If anyone could clear this up for me I'd really appreciate the help!

“I'm struggling to understand why this isn't included in the calculations for energy & entropy changes throughout the cycle?” Because the Carnot cycle is not a real heat engine cycle.


The work of this switching process surely consumes...energy

There is no theoretical reason why a mechanism that continually repeats the same cyclic motion could not do so forever with no energy input. There are only practical reasons (e.g., energy lost to friction in bearings, energy lost to hysteresis in springs, acoustic energy that is radiated into the air or transmitted to the supporting structure.)
Simple example: A freely spinning wheel would continue to spin forever if it spun on a frictionless bearing, and if it spun in vacuum, and if it was shielded from any electromagnetic interactions. Its kinetic energy would be constant (i.e., would not depend on time.)
Another example: A spring pendulum would continue to oscillate forever if there were no hysteresis loss in the spring, if its support structure were absolutely rigid, if it oscillated in vacuum, etc. Its energy would continually change over time between potential energy stored in the spring, to kinetic energy of the pendulum bob, and back to potential energy again.
Other more complicated mechanisms are just variations on that second idea—energy moving in a cycle from one part of the machine to another and back again, from kinetic to potential and back again, without ever being lost.

Ah, thinking of it in terms of something like a frictionless spin between the different states helps- - thanks!


I'm struggling to understand why this isn't included in the
calculations for energy & entropy changes throughout the cycle?

The reason is it would be an unnecessary distraction.
Keeping in mind that the Carnot heat engine cycle is not a real (i.e. practical) cycle, but an idealization, one can always devise theoretical ways to switch reservoirs and add/remove insulation by means of reversible work where the net work is zero with no effect on cycle efficiency. The focus instead should be on the working fluid undergoing reversible work and heat.
Hope this helps.
